# Is it possible to check a second Espresso Intent matcher after you receive the result from the first one?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

When using the `intended(IntentMatcher)` from the Android Espresso API, is it possible to do this twice in the same Activity?

So for example I click a button which starts an Activity for result. I check that this Activity has fired using `intended(IntentMatcher)`. That works.

However, when I get the result, I want to fire off an Intent for a different Activity. In this case just a local Activity in the same app package with no result.

When I do this manually in the app it works fine, but Espresso can't seem to detect the second Intent in my test. What I am I missing or is this not possible? Alternatively, how *should* I be doing it? Maybe my design is bad.

When I do the check I'm trying this:

```
intended(toPackage(<packageName>));
intended(hasComponent(hasClassName(<className>)));
```

The first line matches but not the second one. And even if the second line is not completely correct it never seems to show anything in the error log about the second Activity I'm actually starting.

Another thing adding to the confusion is that two intents are definitely being fired as it shows that in the log. They both seem to be the same one but with slightly different details - one is a package, one is a component. Does it log the result from the first Intent as an Intent in itself? Sounds unlikely but where is this other intent coming from? I know it's not the second Activity I'm launching as it still fires even when that Activity isn't called (when the first Intent result is a fail).

I've also considered that maybe it's not getting detected because it's not waiting long enough for the second intent to fire. If that were the case, what would I do about that? I don't see much talk about handling time sensitive things in Espresso. Like checking if a progress bar is shown but then hidden again while not pressing anything. How do you do that? Maybe it's the same answer.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. My IdlingResource wasn't working.

After fixing that it works like a charm :)